# Populate userform textbox with date taken from cell in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format

Tags: excel, vba, userform, date-formatting

I want to fill a userform textbox with a date taken from a cell. The date in the cell is in 'dd/MM/yyyy' but the date drawn from this cell into the textbox comes always as 'MM/dd/yyyy'. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated as I have been wasting tons of hours on that issue.

```
Text_checkin = DateValue(Sheets("Data").Range("Data_St").Offset(Trgt, 3).Value)
```

Comment: More info is needed, but the textbox should show the format per the regional date settings. I assume the cell format isn't overridden with the different locale (location) value? If you use the month and day functions on the date, does it show the month and day values you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

Computer's system date setting decides how `DateValue` outputs a date. You may want to read about [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

To show the result in a specific format, use the [Format Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Text_checkin = Format(DateValue(Sheets("Data").Range("Data_St").Offset(Trgt, 3).Value), "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
It seems that it works for me:
`Text_checkin = DateValue(Sheets("Data").Range("Data_St").Offset(Trgt, 3).Text)`
The System's regional date settings was set to English (UK) dd/MM/yyyy all the time.